# Why the matrices for integral operator is so different from its approximation?

Tags: matrices, operator-theory

When we try to invert the derivative operator, we get a matrix with infinite elements:

$\frac1{D+s}=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
 \frac{1}{s} & -\frac{1}{s^2} & \frac{2}{s^3} & -\frac{6}{s^4} & \frac{24}{s^5} & -\frac{120}{s^6} & . \\
 0 & \frac{1}{s} & -\frac{2}{s^2} & \frac{6}{s^3} & -\frac{24}{s^4} & \frac{120}{s^5} & . \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{s} & -\frac{3}{s^2} & \frac{12}{s^3} & -\frac{60}{s^4} & . \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{s} & -\frac{4}{s^2} & \frac{20}{s^3} & . \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{s} & -\frac{5}{s^2} & . \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{s} & . \\
 . & . & . & . & . & . & . \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Yet, the antiderivative has a matrix:

$\frac 1D=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & . \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & . \\
 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & . \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & . \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & 0 & . \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{5} & 0 & . \\
 . & . & . & . & . & . & . \\
\end{array}
\right) $

These two matrices do not look similar and the second one is not a limit case of the first. Why it is so?

Can the second one somehow be obtained from the first one?
The $\ln (D+s) $ operator matrix also has infinite elements as $s\to0$:

$\ln (D+s)=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
 \ln s & \frac{1}{s} & -\frac{1}{s^2} & \frac{2}{s^3} & -\frac{6}{s^4} & \frac{24}{s^5} & . \\
 0 & \ln s & \frac{2}{s} & -\frac{3}{s^2} & \frac{8}{s^3} & -\frac{30}{s^4} & . \\
 0 & 0 & \ln s & \frac{3}{s} & -\frac{6}{s^2} & \frac{20}{s^3} & . \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \ln s & \frac{4}{s} & -\frac{10}{s^2} & . \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ln s & \frac{5}{s} & . \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ln s & . \\
 . & . & . & . & . & . & . \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Notice that the elements of $\ln (D+s)$ are antiderivatives of $\frac1{D+s}$ Can we somehow oftain a matrix with finite elements from this, similar to the first example?

Comment: Are you considering the case of small $s$? If so, it might be better to use "perturbation" instead of "approximation" in the title.

Comment: How about "Why is the matrix for the perturbed anti-derivative so dramatically different from the matrix for the un-perturbed form?".

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC "approximation" means "approachment" to me, while I never encountered "prturbation" in mathematics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say
$$
\frac{1}{D} 1 = f
$$
it seems that you want the solution of the differential equation
$$
1 = f'(x)
\tag1$$
with solution $f(x) = x + C$.  You drop the $C$ and you get the first column of your  $1/D$ matrix.  Why do you drop the $C$?

Next, when you say
$$
\frac{1}{D+s} 1 = f
$$
you want the solution of the differential equation
$$
1 = f'(x) + sf(x)
\tag2$$
with solution
$$
\frac{1}{s} + C e^{-sx}
$$
You drop the second term and get the first column of your $1/(D+s)$ matrix.

Maybe it is better so set things up where we do not just drop unwanted terms, but instead specify a way to choose one of the solutions.  For example, what if we specify $f(0)=0$?  Then the solution of $(2)$ is
$$
f_s(x) = \frac{1-e^{-sx}}{s}
\tag3$$
and the solution of $(1)$ is
$$
f_0(x) = x
\tag4$$
and we do have
$$
\lim_{s\to 0} f_s = f_0 .
$$

Comment: Okay, so, can we write a full matrix, that approaches the exact result as $s\to0$? Can we do the same with the logarithm operator so to see the matrix for logarithm as $s=0$?

Comment: The code in Mathematica: Table[DSolveValue[{f'[x] + s f[x] == x^n, f[0] == 0}, f[x], x] // 
  FullSimplify, {n, 0, 4}]
Limit[%, s -> 0] // FullSimplify
Integrate[%%, s] // FullSimplify
Limit[%, s -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"] // FullSimplify
Table[Coefficient[Series[%, {x, 0, 4}], x, k], {k, 0, 4}] // 
  Expand // MatrixForm

Comment: Wait... I obtained the same result as in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4008298/is-this-article-wrong !

Comment: $$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & . \\
 0 & \frac{3}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & . \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{11}{6} & 0 & 0 & . \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{25}{12} & 0 & . \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{137}{60} & . \\
 . & . & . & . & . & . \\
\end{array}
\right)-\log (x)-\gamma$$ Entirely using this answer.